# Spring-WS payload based endpoint mapping unsuccessful in case of WS-Security Encryption

Tags: spring-ws

When using PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping together with WS-Security Encryption, I get this error: [EndpointNotFound] No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData]

Spring WS wants first finding the right Endpoint, and only later decrypts the SOAP body. This is obviously not the right thing to do.

Please dont tell me that the SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping is the solution. Is not there a better way? I would not like routing based on SOAP Action or WS-A Action.

Comment: Ivan is it possible to show us how do you define your custom EndpointMapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the `SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` or `AnnotationActionEndpointMapping` are the only provided mappings you can use.  In Spring-WS, the `EndpointMapping` is queried before any of the interceptors are invoked - including the security interceptor, and such you have to find a mapping that does not depend on the encrypted message payload.

That said, since `EndpointMapping` is an interface, you can also write your own, and include any kind of routing logic you can think of. Extending from `AbstractAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` is a good start for this approach. When your mapping is done, just wire it up in the application context and it should be detected automatically by Spring-WS's `MessageDispatcher`.

Comment: Thanks Arjen for the answer. Writing my own EndpointMapping sounds like an interesting option.

Comment: We managed to solve our problem with a custom EndpointMapping as you proposed. We apply it together with PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping. One of them always finds the right endpoint.